# Data driven Framework Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, data-driven-tests

I automated following scenario :

```
 public void test() throws Exception {

      String home_logo_url="158321";//This Value is to bet get from Excel
      String enough_talk_promo="1057406";

    System.out.println("Check for home_logo_url");  
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    String SiteWindow = driver.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='logo']/a")).click();//This xpath is to bet get from Excel
    for (String PromoWindow : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(PromoWindow); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
    }
        String script = "return rlSerial;";//This is used to get Serial from Open window 
        String value = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
        Assert.assertEquals(value,home_logo_url);
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(SiteWindow);
        System.out.println("Pass");
        }
```

I had created following Sheet:

[image]

Please help me out how to proceed , It is much appreciated if i get working code

Comment: Please stop asking the same question multiple times!

Comment: @gagravarr , Sorry for that , i am not getting my query sorted , stuck badly , Can someone please modify my script to read url , xpath and expected value from sheet ...